# How to use Mongo Bulk Update using its Java Driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java

I am using Mongo Bulk Update using its Java Driver 2.13.

```
    MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = (DB) mongo.getDB("test");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("collection");
    BulkWriteOperation builder = collection.initializeOrderedBulkOperation();
    builder.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", "1")).update(new BasicDBObject("_id", "1").append("name", "dev"));
```

I got the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Update document keys must start with $: _id
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl$Run.executeUpdates(DBCollectionImpl.java:769)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl$Run.execute(DBCollectionImpl.java:734)
at com.mongodb.DBCollectionImpl.executeBulkWriteOperation(DBCollectionImpl.java:149)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeBulkWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:1737)
at com.mongodb.DBCollection.executeBulkWriteOperation(DBCollection.java:1733)
at com.mongodb.BulkWriteOperation.execute(BulkWriteOperation.java:93)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error is because when doing updates you must use an update operator. See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/ for a list of update operators.

From your example I gather you are setting the name field to "dev", so you need to use the `$set` operator like so:

```
builder.find(new BasicDBObject("_id", "1"))
       .update(new BasicDBObject("$set", new BasicDBObject("name", "dev")));
```